# TYPO3 Caching confused

Tags: caching, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

We have a website with a list- and detail-view of records. Every now and then the caching gets confused and instead of the initial list-view a cached detail-view is shown.

The url in question is `<domain>/rathaus-buergerservice/rathaus/mitarbeiter-a-z/` which translates to `index.php?&id=61`.
a possible detail-view would be `<domain>/rathaus-buergerservice/rathaus/mitarbeiter-a-z/ansprechpartner/show/buergerbuero/` which translates to `index.php?&id=61&amp;tx_citkoegovservicelight_ansprechpartner[ansprechpartner]=35&amp;tx_citkoegovservicelight_ansprechpartner[action]=show&cHash=af76fce55ed9f1331122e06fefb43449`.

After some time a call of `<domain>/rathaus-buergerservice/rathaus/mitarbeiter-a-z/` shows a detail-view. It is no browser cache as this can be seen with any browser and any computer independent of any BE-Login.

And as usual: clearing the cache fixes everything.
And it's not reproducable the second call which gets confused. it takes some time and calls.

How can this be inspected in detail?
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Does the extension use its own caching or default caching of TYPO3?

Comment: I think the extension uses TYPO3 caching, but I have to inspect it to get a correct answer.

Comment: Can you check, which kind of tags and conditions are associated with this wrong cache entry?

Comment: as the site is in production I cleared all cache to get a correct display. now I have to wait until the error occurs the next time so I can inspect the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I always have strange errors with the "APCu cache backend" enabled. I always prefer the configuration preset "Database cache backend".